# SQL Query to merge several views into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was trying to create a new view out of 3 or 4 other views/tables.

TableA:

| title_id | homeTeam |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | WSV |
| 5678 | SSV |
| 7890 | NULL |
| 4321 | SCC |

TableB:

| title_id | awayTeam |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | SSV |
| 5678 | SFV |
| 7890 | NULL |
| 4321 | KFC |

TableC:

| title_id | homeTeam |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | SSV |
| 5678 | NULL |
| 7890 | AAB |
| 4711 | BFG |

I would like to generate a new view out of those three which looks like:

| title_id | Teams |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | WSV, SSV, SSV |
| 5678 | SSV, SFV, N/A |
| 7890 | N/A, N/A, AAB |
| 4321 | SCC, KFC, N/A |
| 4711 | N/A, N/A, BFG |

As you can see, NULL should be renamed to N/A, as well if id doesn't exist in one of the other tables. And I would like to get DISTINCT title_id.

@DaleK sure, i tried it like this:

> select tableA.title_id, ISNULL(tableA.homeTeam, 'N/A') + ',' +
> ISNULL(tableB.awayTeam, 'N/A') + ',' + ISNULL(tableC.homeTeam, 'N/A')
> as Teams from tableA, tableB, tableC;

This leads into an neverending query for my tables which has each more than 300k rows.

Next i tried join:

> select tableA.title_id, ISNULL(tableA.homeTeam, 'N/A') + ',' +
> ISNULL(tableB.awayTeam, 'N/A') + ',' + ISNULL(tableC.homeTeam, 'N/A')
> as Teams from tableA  FULL JOIN tableB ON tableB.title_id =
> tableA.title_id FULL JOIN tableC ON tableC.title_id = tableA.tile_id

But to be honest i wasnt sure about the number of rows.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at `UNION (ALL)` and string aggregation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `UNION ALL` the tables together, then use string aggregation

```
SELECT
  t.title_id,
  STRING_AGG(ISNULL(t.team, 'N/A'), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.ordering) AS team
FROM (
    SELECT 
      a.title_id,
      a.homeTeam AS team,
      1 AS ordering
    FROM TableA a

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
      b.title_id,
      b.awayTeam,
      2
    FROM TableB b

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
      c.title_id,
      c.homeTeam,
      3
    FROM TableC c
) t
GROUP BY
  t.title_id;
```

For SQL Server 2016 and earlier, you have to use the `FOR XML` method, and it's less efificent as you have to query the tables multiple times

```sql
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 
      a.title_id,
      a.homeTeam AS team,
      1 AS ordering
    FROM TableA a

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
      b.title_id,
      b.awayTeam,
      2
    FROM TableB b

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
      c.title_id,
      c.homeTeam,
      3
    FROM TableC c
)
SELECT
  tOuter.title_id,
  STUFF(tInner.team.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, LEN(', '), '') AS team
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT t.title_id
    FROM t
) tOuter
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT ', ' + ISNULL(t.team, 'N/A')
    FROM t
    WHERE t.title_id = tOuter.title_id
    ORDER BY t.ordering
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
) tInner(team);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c9828b7c94ed018161039c6ffd0f37cd)

Comment: Maybe this will work in SQL Server 2017 but i'm using 2014. I have to use stuff here or?

Comment: Yes you can use `FOR XML`, given you that also

Comment: Hey @Charlieface, thanks for that i gave it a try but receiving: The multi-part identifier "t.title_id" could not be bound. ? As well i think in front of 2 and 3 is a comma needed. Why does it give me that error? Because of title_id is is name of all three columns?

Comment: Should be all fixed now. No it wasn't that, it was because I used `t` instead of `tOuter`

Comment: This will work, but will say this XML trick is neat and needed for older SQL versions, but it has horrible performance issues. So if you expect to have a significant amount of data and/or expect this to be run frequently, watch out. It may work quickly today, but may not work in a month. I've seen FOR XML struggle with even just a few thousand rows. I'd think @nismotri's solution would probably perform better(once the bugs are address that I noted in the comments)

Comment: I'd agree with you, except that I'd recommend upgrading to a newer version anyway. There are methods to speed this up, basically you need to get the outer part into an indexed temp table first

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select
    COALESCE(a.title_id,b.title_id,c.title_id),
    CONCAT(
        ISNULL(a.homeTeam,'N/A'),
        ISNULL(b.awayTeam,'N/A'),
        ISNULL(c.homeTeam,'N/A'),
        ) 'Teams',
from TableA a
    full join TableB b on a.title_id = b.title_id
    full join TableC c on c.title_id = a.title_id
where 
    a.homeTeam is not null 
    OR b.awayTeam is not null
    OR c.homeTeam is not null
group by a.title_id
```

As for the DISTINCT title_id, it should be unique by default as I assume it is used as the key in each of the tables.

Comment: This doesn't output title_id '4711' from TableC, though.

Comment: @waka is right, this misses some outputs.

Comment: Agreed, updated the query

Comment: Think you need to replace ```a.title_id``` in your SELECT and GROUP BY with ```COALESCE(a.title_id,b.title_id,c.title_id)```. This should account for where ID's are in table b and/or c and not in a

Comment: Also should replace your CASE WHEN's with ISNULL, no need for a CASE WHEN here